# RSelenium UnknownError - java.lang.IllegalStateException with Google Chrome

Tags: java, r, selenium, rselenium

I am running the following script based on the [RSelenium Basics CRAN page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html):

```
library(RSelenium)
startServer(args = c("-port 4455"), log = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
```

This produces the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Selenium is already running on port 4444. Or some other service is.
 at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.start(SeleniumServer.java:492)
 at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:305)
 at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:245)
 at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncher.main(GridLauncher.java:64)
```

Based on the comments from [this conversation on GitHub](https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues/34), I've modified my `startServer()` command like so:

```
startServer(args = c("-port 4455"), log = FALSE, invisible = FALSE)
```

I then receive the following error in my console:

```
Error:   Summary: UnknownError
 Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
 class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
```

And this error in the Java prompt that pops up:

```
14:38:55.098 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
14:38:55:161 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 25.40-b25
14:38:55.161 INFO - OS: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
14:38:55.161 INFO - v2.46.0, with Core v2.46.0. Built from revision 87c69e2
14:38:55.209 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
14:38:55.209 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
14:38:55:289 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4455/wd/hub
14:38:55:289 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

I'm not sure if the lack of an Opera driver is an actual error or just a warning.  Regardless, I would like to use Chrome, so it seems like it shouldn't matter.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have chromedriver accessible from somewhere in your PATH. https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was finally able to get RSelenium to work by piecing together information from a number of different sources.  I think it would be helpful to have all of this information in one location, so here is the process that I went through to get RSelenium to work on Windows 7 (64-bit) with Chrome as the browser:

1. **Download the [64-bit version of Java](https://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).**  I could not get anything to work with the standard download.
2. **Download [ChromeDriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/).**
3. **Download the [Selenium Standalone Server](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) or run `checkForServer()` from R.**
4. **Create a batch file to start the Selenium server.**  I initially tried to use `startServer()` from an R script, but it would frequently get stuck and not carry on to the next line in the script.  Here is the batch file that I created:

   ```
   java -jar C:\path\to\selenium-server-standalone.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe
   ```

   ChromeDriver can be put in the PATH environmental variable, but I decided to add in the path to ChromeDriver to the batch file (which accomplishes the same goal).
5. **Run the R script.**  Here is my final script:

   ```
   library(RSelenium)
   shell.exec(paste0("C:\\path\\to\\yourbatchfile.bat"))
   Sys.sleep(5)

   remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
   remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
   remDr$navigate("http://www.google.com")
   ```

   The `Sys.sleep()` call was necessary because I would get an error in the `remoteDriver()` call if it ran before the Selenium Server had finished starting.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that RSelenium has some annoying differences for OSX. The invisible=T/silent=T arguments will not work when you run the yourcommand.command file and the remDr$open() method, respectively. The invisible=T will actually remind you that it only works on Windows. Not a huge deal (and if someone has a workaround I'd appreciate it).

For posterity's sake here's a slight variation for OSX to replace shell.exec using a .command file instead of a .bat with the same contents as above:

**yourcommand.command file contents**

```
java -jar /path/to/selenium-server-standalone.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver
```

**R script modification**

```
library(RSelenium)
system(paste("open","/path/to/yourcommand.command"))
Sys.sleep(5)
...
```