# Scraping website that include JS/jquery code with R

Tags: jquery, json, r, web-scraping

I want to extract the hyperlinks from [this website](http://karakterstatistik.stads.ku.dk/) with different searches (dont be scared that it is in Danish) . The hyperlinks can be found to the right (v15, v14, v13 etc) [[example](http://karakterstatistik.stads.ku.dk/#searchText=&term=&block=&institute=2346&faculty=2710&searchingCourses=true&page=1)].
The website I try to scrape somehow uses the search results from some kind of a jquery/javascript. This is based on my *very* limited knowledge in HTML and might be wrong.

I think this fact makes the following code unable to run (I use the "rvest"-package):

```
sdslink="http://karakterstatistik.stads.ku.dk/#searchText=&term=&block=&institute=null&faculty=&searchingCourses=true&page=1"
s_link = recs %>% 
read_html(encoding = "UTF-8") %>% 
html_nodes("#searchResults a") %>% 
html_attr("href")
```

I have found a method that works but it requires me to download the pages manually with "right click"+"save as" for each page. This is however unfeasible as I want to scrape a total of 100 pages for hyperlinks.

I have tried to use the jsonlite package combined with httr but I am not able to find the right .json file it seems.

I hope you guys might have a solution, either to get the jsonlite to work, automate the "save as" solution or a third more clever path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html).  Here's some simple code to get you started.  I assume you already have RSelenium and a webdriver installed.  Navigate to your site of interest:

```
library(RSelenium)
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, 
                      browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
remDr$navigate("http://karakterstatistik.stads.ku.dk/")
```

Find the `submit` button by inspecting the source:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "submit")
webElem$clickElement()
```

Save the first 5 pages:

```
html_source <- vector("list", 5)
i <- 1
while (i <= 5) {
  html_source[[i]] <- remDr$getPageSource()
  webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "next")
  webElem$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(2)
  i <- i + 1
}
remDr$close()
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help it was **exactly what I needed**. Had to look a bit into Selenium before I could get it to work. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31188481/6717092) to another question was very useful if other people are experiencing trouble installing.

Comment: You're welcome -- please mark the answer as accepted if your question has been answered satisfactorily.

Comment: Done and thanks. I have a fairly quick [follow-up question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38991773/6717092)