# Scraping HTML from vector of strings in R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

Building on an answer to a [former question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38974684/6717092) I'm scraping [this website](http://karakterstatistik.stads.ku.dk/) for links with the Rselenium-package using the following code:

```
startServer() 
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4444, 
                  browserName = "chrome")

remDr$open(silent = TRUE)
remDr$navigate("http://karakterstatistik.stads.ku.dk/")
Sys.sleep(2)

webElem <- remDr$findElement("name", "submit")
webElem$clickElement()
Sys.sleep(5)

html_source <- vector("list", 100)
i <- 1
while (i <= 100) {
  html_source[[i]] <- remDr$getPageSource()
  webElem <- remDr$findElement("id", "next")
  webElem$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(2)
  i <- i + 1
}
Sys.sleep(3)
remDr$close()
```

When I want to scrape the above created vector of strings (html_source) using the rvest-package I get an error as the source is not an HTML-file:

```
kar.links = html_source %>% 
  read_html(encoding = "UTF-8") %>% 
  html_nodes("#searchResults a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")
```

I've tried to collapse the vector and tried to look for a string-to-HTML converter, but nothing seems to work.
I feel the solution lies somewhere in how I save the page-sources in the loop.

**EDIT**: fixed it by this less than beautiful solution:

```
links <- vector("list", 100)
i <- 1
while (i <= 100) {
links[[i]] <- html_source[[i]][[1]] %>% 
  read_html(encoding = "UTF-8") %>% 
  html_nodes("#searchResults a") %>% 
  html_attr("href") 
i <- i + 1
}
col_links<- links %>% 
unlist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html_source` is a nested list:

```
str(head(html_source, 3))
# List of 3
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ : chr "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>\n    <title>Karakterfordeling</title>\n    <link rel=\"icon\"| __truncated__
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ : chr "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>\n    <title>Karakterfordeling</title>\n    <link rel=\"icon\"| __truncated__
#  $ :List of 1
#   ..$ : chr "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>\n    <title>Karakterfordeling</title>\n    <link rel=\"icon\"| __truncated__
```

In your case, `html_source` is made up of 100 elements; each element is itself a list with one element, which is a string (and the raw html code).  Therefore, to get each raw html page, you need to access `html_source[[1]][[1]]`, `html_source[[2]][[1]]`, and so on.

To flatten `html_source`, you can do: `` lapply(html_source, `[[`, 1) ``.  We get the same result if we use `remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]` in the `while` loop:

```
str(head(html_source, 3))
# List of 3
#  $ : chr "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>\n    <title>Karakterfordeling</title>\n    <link rel=\"icon\"| __truncated__
#  $ : chr "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>\n    <title>Karakterfordeling</title>\n    <link rel=\"icon\"| __truncated__
#  $ : chr "<!DOCTYPE html><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><head>\n    <title>Karakterfordeling</title>\n    <link rel=\"icon\"| __truncated__
```

Comment: Thanks again. The html_source[[1]][[1]] method works like a charm, so I am able to extract the links from each object on the list. The lapply() function works as well. So in order to get the links from each of the 100 objects I have to loop the hrvest functions? Or is there another way so this can be done in one simple step?
_EDIT: pressed enter too soon_

Comment: You could collapse the list using `unlist`, then use `paste(..., collapse = "")` to get one (very) long character string, that you can then parse for links.

Comment: Using the following code w/ and w/o the lapply-function only produce a vector of 179 links for some reason?

    flat<-lapply(html_source, `[[`, 1) %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    paste(collapse = '')


    links <- flat %>% 
      read_html(encoding = "UTF-8") %>% 
      html_nodes("#searchResults a") %>% 
      html_attr("href")

Comment: Found a solution, I have edited it into the question